# How to present a ViewController with a UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm attempting to present an `ImagePicker`, and there after the user has selected an image, present an image editing `ViewController` where the user can manipulate the image and then send the edited image back to the original `ViewController`.

> **Question:**
>
> Is there a standard or best practice approach starting with an initial ViewControlle, then present an ImagePicker there after another ViewController to do the imaging editing, and then display it all back in the initial ViewController, all while making the transitions
>    look seamless?
>
> Is the suggestion in Try 3 below a good practice method or is there a better example of how to achieve this?

*Try 1.*

My initial thought was to present the `ImagePicker` programmatically via code below, followed by the image editing `ViewController` after the image is selected. But that approach didn’t seem right. I couldn’t seem to get the `ImagePicker` to segue properly to the `ViewController` after an image was picked. (A bunch of *“Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value”* errors were showing for the editing `ViewController`.)

```
    let imagePicker = MyImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*Try 2.*

My second attempt was to present an image editing `ViewController` as a hidden/transparent followed immediately by the `ImagePicker` loaded , but that causes some flashes of an empty background.

*Try 3.*

So I came across this suggestion which is a variation of my second try using the window background to show an image of the current `ViewController` which seems possible. http://xissburg.com/presenting-multiple-modal-view-controllers-at-once/

*Try 4.*

My other idea is to create a separate `ViewController` that handles just a `ImagePicker`, and then connect each `ViewController` via segues in the interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try like this, on your first `ViewController` show the picker on `viewDidLoad` with no presenting animation.

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Now on

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        //Present your custom editing controller also create `protocol/delegate` for getting editing image back.
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I sort of get what you are saying about no presenting animation, but when I put that into `viewDidLoad` it doesn't work, I get a warning `"Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController:  on   whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"`

Comment: @user4806509 Have you try on `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`, check that give reply.

Comment: Thanks, `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` worked, not sure why I missed that, seems obvious. Still getting that warning though...

Comment: @user4806509 Are you using auto-layout? If so, elements on auto-layout are not loaded when viewDidAppear() is called.