# How to send UIImage from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo with Segue?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, uiimagepickercontroller

So what I have:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[String : Any]) {
    let tempImage: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let imagetoTransmit: UIImage = tempImage
    shootedImage = imagetoTransmit
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "cameraSegueIdent", sender: nil)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

where Segue:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "cameraSegueIdent" {
        let imageToTransmit: UIImage = shootedImage
        let viewController = (segue.destination as! TakenPhotoPreviewViewController)
        viewController.takenImage = imageToTransmit
    } 
}
```

The Image is being sent, but the Segue does not perform.
Please help!

**UPDATE**

I went with the idea to send the image as sender, without saving in current ViewController and it worked like a charm!

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[String : Any]) {

    let tempImage: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "cameraSegueIdent", sender: tempImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Maybe do the `performSegue` in the completion of the dismiss?

Comment: You need to do something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39146965/6433023 in this answer of my i have present new controller instead of that in the completion block you need to call `performSegue` method.

Answer (score 0):

Following might helpful.

```
    let tempImage: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let imagetoTransmit: UIImage = tempImage
    shootedImage = imagetoTransmit
    _ picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "cameraSegueIdent", sender: nil)
    })
```

Also, make sure that the segue identifier is correctly configured in your storyboard.

Comment: tried like that, but that didn't solved the problem, anyway i figured out how to do it and Updated my Question. Thanks!